# URL is being transformed; / being added in front of ? in URL, even though source doesn't include the /

Tags: html, url, browser, transform

In the HTML code below, notice there is no '/' between the _ and ? after the word **config**

```
<html>
<body>
      <a href="http://config_?Token=blah1234">http://config_?Token=blah1234</a>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when this HTML is loaded into a browser (behavior appears to be browser agnostic), something is causing a '/' to be added between the _ and ?, so when you hover over the URL and/or click on it, you're seeing/navigating to:

```
http://config_/?Token=blah1234
```

..and not

```
http://config_?Token=blah1234
```

...which is a broken link because of the erroneous '/' that got added

Not sure what's causing this or how to prevent it. Any ideas? Thanks ahead of time...

Comment: Since you put `http://` in front of it, the browser has no other choice than to assume `config_` was the _host name_ you wanted to make the request to, and since `?` begins the query string, the browser _has_ to insert the slash, because a _correct_ absolute URL can not consist of an empty path between host name and query string. So, what do you _actually_ want to link to? A file/folder named `config_`? Then remove the `http://`, which in this case makes no sense at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the format....it's a config URL for a mobile app that is provided by the vendor where the app is set to open config_ URLs, which it does, but the slash messes up the query string value being passed in....Agree with your comments and standard formatting, I was just hoping for some sort of workaround...

Comment: Hm, who passes in what and from where? How much of this URL do you configure/specify, which part of it is under control of the vendor? (And this mobile app decided to somehow inject itself into the DNS resolution process, and listens locally on port 80 for requests to the host name `config_` ... or how does this work? Sounds like a rather weird setup. Not a native app then? Otherwise the usual way to get it started from the context of a web page and pass parameters would be a custom protocol ...)

Comment: I don't control any any it. I download the app, they send the specific config URL as per the format above..
 
I was wrong in my above comment, it does not launch the app, it launches failed DNS probe error in a browser dialogue...

Comment: And the token value is being passed to the app

Comment: Then I don't think you got much of a chance, other than talking to the vendor and asking them to fix this on their end - so that their part of this can handle a leading slash before the query string. In don't think you will get common browsers to handle this any differently, no matter how that URL is navigated to - a link, JS, submitting a form, ... are likely to all go through the same URL handling routine.

Comment: I was afraid of that, and honestly felt like that was the answer as well. Thanks for the dialogue and confirmation. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

All moder browers auto add a slash to the end of the url.

[Take a look at this thread.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser)